# How to set ansible mitogen strategy on playbook?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible

I'm trying to make it work mitogen strategy on my ansible playbook. I'm following tutorial on [mitogen tutorial](https://dev.to/sshnaidm/speed-up-ansible-with-mitogen-2c3j). My python version is 3.6 and ansible version is 2.7.10.

Mitogen is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy`

When I try to add keys on my playbook as:

```
  - hosts: "{{ host_group | default('host-list') }}"
    ...
    strategy: mitogen_linear
    strategy_plugins: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy
```

I have the following error:

```
ERROR! 'strategy_plugins' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

Also, I'm trying to configure it as a environment variable in playbook execution:

```
command = ['ANSIBLE_STRATEGY_PLUGINS=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy', 'ANSIBLE_STRATEGY=mitogen_linear', 'ansible-playbook', '-ihosts', 'ansible_scripts/inventory.yml']
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Here is not finding directory:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ANSIBLE_STRATEGY_PLUGINS=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy': 'ANSIBLE_STRATEGY_PLUGINS=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy'
```

How I can correctly configure mitogen strategy on my playbook? How I can make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be some misconfiguration `"No such file or directory"`. Try the configuration file. For example put into the *[defaults]* section:

```
$ grep strategy /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
strategy_plugins = /usr/local/ansible/plugins/ansible_mitogen/plugins/strategy
strategy = mitogen_linear
```

Fit the configuration file and path to your needs. (Works for me with ansible 2.7.9 and mitogen-0.2.6)

FWIW, if you want to automate the installation and configuration see [plugins.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-ansible/blob/master/tasks/plugins.yml) and example of [vars](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-ansible/blob/master/vars/main.yml).

Comment: How do you know if mitogen is working as a strategy on a playbook?

Comment: @eduardosufan if you add verbosity `-vvvv` at your command line, you will see mitogen debug messages